# How can I set the style in ExtJs actionColumn items?

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs

I have the next piece of code

```
{
xtype: 'actionColumn',
id: 'act_id',
width: 30,
flex: 0,
items: [{
     getClass: function(v, meta, record) {
       if(record.get('blahblah') == true)
         return 'aClassName';
       else
         return 'aOtherClassName';
     }
   }]
}
```

Ok this piece of code working fine, but I like adding a style in line in my icon, but when I use something like:

```
{
xtype: 'actionColumn',
id: 'act_id',
width: 30,
flex: 0,
items: [{
     getClass: function(v, meta, record) {
       if(record.get('blahblah') == true)
         return 'aClassName';
       else
         return 'aOtherClassName';
     },
     style: {'width':'16px'}
   }]
}
```

Nothing happen. I try a 1000 different ways but nothing, and in the ExtJs 4 I can't find anything about this.

Comment: I know that the fast way is creating a class, but I need in this case style inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
xtype: 'actionColumn',
id: 'act_id',
width: 30,
flex: 0,
items: [{
     getClass: function(v, meta, record) {
       meta.attr = "style='width:16px;'";
       if(record.get('blahblah') == true)
         return 'aClassName';
       else
         return 'aOtherClassName';
     }
   }]
}
```